# Final render is blank

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I'm new to Blender and last night I was working on a simple animation of cubes falling onto a plane. I saved the blender file and today when I opened it up and tried to render it, it refused to work. If I start a new project and render it, it works fine.

I've made sure that I have lighting, and I've messed with the output settings, but I can't get it to render. I was able to render the entire animation earlier today, but I closed out of Blender and when I reopened it, it renders blank.

This is how it looks when I change to render view in the viewport.
[image: Render view]

Then this is what the final rendering looks like. 
[image: Final rendering]

Here's the [.blend](https://mega.co.nz/#!CYNWySqZ!mh5zXpxRrgSaEnEbM6nnLy3IFNjq6pPOvQpBxSm1oaw)

Comment: Can you post a .blend, I't is very hard to guess what is the cause or your issue?

Comment: yes, you're right, that fix worked for me. Thanks for the help